# Create ER diagram from a file-based SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-relationship, erd

I have an MDF and LDF file and would like to have an ER diagram created. I do have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Does it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, the GUI for working with SQL Server 2008R2 has "database diagrams" but they are more of a visual way to physically work with tables, objects, keys etc.  Not really for generating logical ER diagrams.  Plus, the "database diagrams" within SSMS do not have features for printing, arranging into heiarchies, orthogonal shapes etc. or scripting from the ER Diagram like most data modeling tools do.  SSMS has a lot of features for scripting, just not from the database diagram section of the tool.

If you want to get an ER diagram from an MDF/LDF however, one thing is for certain.  You're going to have to attach it as database first no matter what tool you end up using.  I'm not aware of any tool that's going to do that for you right from the MDF.

I use Embarcadero ER Studio a lot for reverse engineering databases into logical ER Diagrams.  You can always download a trial version of it or another similar product from anyone in that space, if you just need a one time go but like I said, you'll first have to attach the database.

For instructions on attaching a database to an instance of SQL Server 2008 refer to BOL here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190209(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. I could not articulate my question earlier. Yes, please. All I want is the database diagram that SQL Server Management Studio generates from a database. I have posted a new question about this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32321636/303685