# This backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I just want to generate a database diagram from my MDF file that was created by my Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET MVC template project.

The following pictures reveal the version of SQL Server, management studio that I have and the error message I receive when I click on the 'New database diagram' context menu.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've really been at this for quite a long while. Please help.

**Note**: I've seen other threads reporting this problem but honestly, I find the answers there unintelligible solely due to my lack of expertise in using database tools.

Comment: Looks like the problem might be that you are connecting to SQL server version 12 (SQL 2014) with tools version 11 (SQL 2012). Try downloading and using SQL Server 2014 SSMS.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you. I am trying that now. Will report back.

Comment: @codemonkeh I'd read that thread before posting. It is related but not the same question.

Comment: The fundamental problem is the same though, you are using a 2012 version of Sql Server Management Studio to connection to a SQL 2014 database (v 12). As @Nick.McDermaid said, just update your tools and try again :)

Comment: @codemonkeh Yes. It's easy for someone who uses these things day in and day out. For someone who doesn't, it's a bit of a nervous breakdown every time one of these things happen to you. :-)

Comment: @codemonkeh For instance, without Nick having told me, I would have spent another 3 or more hours in discovering that version 12.0 of the database is actually not SQL Server 2012 but is SQL Server 2014. And version 11 of the Management Studio goes with SQL Server 2012. You see? If you're not in these trenches daily, you need an old priest and a young one even to figure out what the other answers mean and how they're different from your problem.

Comment: Well to be fair the version of SSMS is 11 and the version of SQL is 12... then I just looked up SQL Server versions. But I feel your pain! its frustrating to be bombarded with info that it's difficult to make sense of. However I do thoroughly commend you on the effort you put into with your question. Most people can't be bothered making the slightest effort themselves. Well done.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you for the remark about being detailed in my question. I try to be most of the times. And thank you also for recommending that I install SQL Server Management Studio 2014. My problem went away with that installation and I was able to create a diagram. If you would like to, please write that as an answer which I will mark as the correct one so others facing this problem know what to do. :-)

Comment: No worries. I'll just leave as duplicate for now - it's fine by me :)

Comment: Microsoft will be adding a Check for Updates feature in the next release of SSMS, which should hopefully mean these issues are less prevalent.